# Run time Error :stack around `szDeviceType ` is corrupted

Tags: c++

Hi I am getting a Run time Error saying that the stack around `szDeviceType` is corrupted but I have no idea, i'm very new to c++ so I wouldn't have the most knowledge. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
int szDeviceType = 0;
char lpszString[MAX_PATH];
LPWSTR szComport = NULL;
LPWSTR szNumChannels = NULL;
char szChannels[MAX_PATH];
char szPort[MAX_PATH];

hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "GetDatascanInfo");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

hr = WcaGetIntProperty(L"DEVICETYPE",&szDeviceType);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get Device Type");

hr = WcaGetFormattedProperty(L"COMPORT",&szComport);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get Com Port");

wcstombs(szPort, szComport, 500);

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"NUMCHANNELS",&szNumChannels);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get Com Port");

wcstombs(szChannels, szNumChannels, 500);

    if(szDeviceType == 2)
    {
        strcat(lpszString, "datascan");
        strcat(lpszString, szPort);
        strcat(lpszString, "DATASCAN 7000,DS:");
        strcat(lpszString, szChannels);

    }
    if (szDeviceType == 3)
    {
        strcat(lpszString, "solo");
        strcat(lpszString, szPort);
        strcat(lpszString, "DATASCAN SOLO,SA:");
        strcat(lpszString, szChannels);

    }
    if (szDeviceType == 4)
    {
        strcat(lpszString, "dataweb");
        strcat(lpszString, szPort);
        strcat(lpszString, "DATAWEB,DW:");
        strcat(lpszString, szChannels);
    }

    hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "DATASCANINFO",  lpszString);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to set DATASCANINFO");


LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

Comment: That error effectively says "there has been a buffer overflow!!!"

Comment: I realize that but I cannot pinpoint where..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks suss:

```
wcstombs(szPort, szComport, 500);
```

The last parameter is the maximum number of characters to write, but your array is only `MAX_PATH` in size which is 260.

You're also using `strcat` to append to `lpszString` without checking whether that overflows.  You should probably switch to using `strcat_s` which has bounds checking.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but am still getting the error about `szDeviceType`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger?  Just keep watching `szDeviceType` and see what tramples it.

Comment: You have the same problem with wcstombs(szChannels, szNumChannels, 500);  That 500 is not just a magic number.  You are are telling the compiler how big your buffer is, but you are giving it incorrect information.

Comment: Yes nothing seems wrong, It is picking up the correct information and then I am getting this error at the end of the function.

Comment: I have changed them all to 260, thanks for the tip, i copied and pasted from a website #1 blunder..:) Thanks @benj changed `strcat`..:)